# How to predict any combination of strings that can occur with given strings?

Tags: python, pandas, prediction, predict

I have some strings in my dataframe and I have replaced it.

```
df2['x'].replace(['APPEAL','AppealNo.','AppealNO.','Co.Appeal','COMP.APPL','Co.Appeal','Comp.','AppealNo','CoAppealnies','CoAppealnies','companyappealno.''CompAPPNo.','CApealNo','CApeal','companyappeal'],'CoAppeal', regex=True,inplace=True)
```

Is there a way where I can predict the future combinations of strings in python with the given strings so I can replace it without doing the process manually?

Comment: What do you mean by "future combinations"? Some function that takes `CoAppeal` and returns a list of variations that will likely appear in your data?

Comment: yes any further combinations that occur at some point when im fetching data.

Comment: There is a concept of *distance*, which given an arbitrary string `x`, you can compute the distance between `x` and `"CoAppeal"`, and if that distance is small enough, you'll make the replacement. The two are equivalent, in the sense that the list you want is the list of all strings with a small enough distance, but definging the distance function is likely easier than searching all possible strings.

Comment: Can you write down the code?

Comment: This is more of a "the function exists, but it's not obvious which exact function you need" situation. A simple example is [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), but this is unlikely to be sufficient in your case.

Comment: Okay thanks I will study about these concepts

Comment: (Just as an example, the string `"corral"` probably has a smaller Levenshtein distance than many of the words you want to replace.)

Comment: Perhaps you can look in the `fuzzywuzzy` package. It has some interesting function that utilizes Levenshtein distance if I'm not mistaken